# How to disable a jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have a simple Problem. I will show a Image and some Text in a fancybox by an ajax call. This is working very well. However I use the okzoom.js to magnifier the image. I want to enable/disable the magnifier function yy a input checkbox. It is possible to enable the function, but I'm not able to stop it:

```
$('#magnifierToggle').change(function (evt) {
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#zoom').okzoom({
            width: 120,
            height: 120,
            scaleWidth: 3000,
            border: "1px solid black",
            shadow: "0 0 5px #000"
        });
    } else {
        $('#zoom').okzoom.func = null; // these function doesen't work
        //$("#zoom").off('okzoom');  
        //delete $('#zoom').fn.func;
    }
});
```

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems current no way to destroy the event.

You can try cloning and replacing it.

```
else {
    $('#zoom').replaceWith($('#zoom').clone());
}
```

(If you any have other events like `click` on `#zoom`, pass true to `clone(true)`